# Estimating a MS-ARMA(p,q)-GARCH(r,s) parameters via MCMC

Tags: bayesian, estimation, arima, markov-process, garch

I am currently working on a MS-ARMA-GARCH model proposed by Dhiman das on this [paper](http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/sce2004/up.27698.1075991479.pdf), and trying to fit it on simulated data.

So far I understand the model and its construction, but I'm having a hard time while trying to understand his MCMC Algorithm (I'm not a statistician, just a math undergraduate student).

Note that his MS-ARMA(p,q)-GARCH(r,s) model follows the form:

\begin{align}
  {y_t} &= \gamma {x_t} + {u_t} \\
  {u_t} &= \sum\limits_{j = 1}^p {{\phi _j}{u_{t - j}} + {\varepsilon _t}  + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^q {{\theta _j}{\varepsilon _{t - j}}} , \hspace{0.5cm}{\varepsilon _t}|{\mathcal{F}_{t - 1}} \sim \mathbf{N}(0,\sigma _t^2)} \\
  \sigma _t^2 &= {\mu _0} + {\mu _1}{S_t} + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^r {{\alpha _j}{u_{t - j}}}  + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^s {{\beta _j}\sigma _{t - j}^2}
\end{align}

Where $\gamma$ is the regression coefficient; $\sigma _{t}^{2}$ is the conditional variance of $\varepsilon$, $S_t$ is an auxiliary variable which follows a Markov Switching model taking integer values in [0,1], ${{\theta }_{j}}$ y ${{\phi }_{j}}$ are ARMA(p,q) model parameters; ${{\alpha }_{j}}$,${{\beta }_{j}}$ are GARCH(r,s) model parameters.

First he follows a [Nakatsuma's paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=9D8B11FE5A44630A2ADFA0EEA8459173?doi=10.1.1.476.5024&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and divides parameters for ARMA ($\delta_1$) and MS-GARCH ($\delta_2$), and treats presample error $\epsilon_0$ as a parameter.

All of these parameters are going to be estimated via MCMC Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.

But, currently I'm stuck trying to understand the proposal distribution for $\gamma$ in Nakatsuma's paper, exactly what are 1,2,3 shown on the picture and how to calculate them.

[[image: Nakatsuma proposal distribution for <span class=]$\gamma$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ7a9.png)

I really appreciate any help you can provide.